# How to paint by events in flutter?

Tags: flutter, events, draw, paint

It's like drawing many different stars on the sky, once a star by a event which tell you where and what the shape the star should be.

I tried CustomPainter, it works but not in the way I need.

Comment: so what does not work in `CustomPainter`? what you mean by "by events"?

Comment: in CustomPainter, paint() do all the painting in one time, and prepare to do it again, but I need it to be done by many events, events means user inputs from some hardware, but not touch screen

Comment: what is the difference if your data comes from some hardware or touch screen? data is data, no matter where it comes from, maybe post some code describing your problem

Comment: not touch screen means GestureDetector would not solve it, I need to paint stars one by one, by the user input, like a human painter, not a printer, as I see, CustomPainter was designed to be a printer..

Comment: Maybe I didn't make it clear enough, I mean for each input, draw 1 star without repaint previous stars, like CustomPainter do.

Comment: there is no such way: you have to draw everything - so if you had 99 stars and want to draw another one then you need to draw all 100 stars

Comment: I see, although that looks wasteful, but that's how it works, it's designed to be always ready for screen view switch, thank you, pskink.